Azure SQL Database Migration Failure: Issues with Tables Containing Encrypted Data
I am trying to migrate a local SQL database to an Azure SQL database using Azure Data Studio and the Azure SQL Migration instance. However, the migration fails for tables containing encrypted data (using the Always Encrypted feature).
Steps Taken:

Configured the Azure SQL Migration extension in Azure Data Studio.
Selected the local database for migration, which includes several tables with columns encrypted using Always Encrypted.
Initiated the migration to Azure SQL Database.

Issue:
The migration fails, and I encounter the following error:

Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 3.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=4816,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=4,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=4816,State=4,Message=Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 3.,},],'

How can I fix this error?

Disable Always Encrypted on columns?

Hey @Osura Dissanayake, please check below answer and let me know it is helpful or not.

@Bhavani This answer was really helpful  and with my additional effort the issue was sorted.

Hey Osura Dissanayake mark it as answer, then it will be helpful to community who are having same issue.

@OsuraDissanayake: Good to accept the solution if it has helped. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO link


Failure happened on 'Sink' side. ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed. Please search error to get more details.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 3.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=4816,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=4,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=4816,State=4,Message=Invalid column type from bcp client for colid 3.,},],'

You are trying to migrate the tables containing encrypted data (using the Always Encrypted feature) from On -premises to Azure SQL Database. But there is no way to migrate Always Encrypted Columns using current form of Azure SQL Migration extension in Azure Data Studio, that may be the reason get above error. To resolve above error, you can utilize Import Export Wizard tool.

To load encrypted data without performing metadata checks on the server during bulk copy operations, create the user with the ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS option illustrated here.
For more information you can refer to the similar post in MS Q&A portal.

Osura Dissanayake : Good to accept the solution if it has helped. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO link
